# Taylor expansion with geometric series

Tags: taylor-expansion

Expand $1/x $ a taylor series around $x=1$. Use $\frac {1}{1-(1-x)}$ and used the geometric series.

I know $\sum (1-x)^n = \frac {1}{1-(1-x)}$, $-1 <x -1<1$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry. My question is how to find this expansion of Taylor of 1/x

Comment: But the answer and the reason why this answer, are already written down in your question...

Comment: So I do not know how to use the geometric series to find taylor expansion in 1 / x. In the book the answer is $\sum (-1)^n (x-1)^n $

Comment: You only need to use that $1-x = (-1)(x-1)$ to get your answer on that form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want the Taylor Series around $x=a$ it is

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k!}f^{(k)}(a)(x-a)^k}$$

so an expression for the k-th derivative of $f(x)$ is needed.

$$f(x)=x^{-1} \implies f^{(k)}(x)=(-1)^k k! x^{-k-1}$$

so for $a=1$, $f^{(k)}(1)=(-1)^k k!$. Therefore, the Taylor-Maclaurin series is

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^k (x-1)^k}$$

with convergence for $-1 <x -1<1$.

---

This is more easily obtained from the geometric series, as you had it. The two methods must agree.

$$f(x) = \frac {1}{1-(1-x)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1-x)^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^n(x-1)^n}$$