# Need help determining Taylor series and convergence interval for $f(x)=1/x$ around $x=1$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am having trouble determining the Taylor series and convergence interval for $f(x)=1/x$ around $x=1$. I have attempted the problem, but I'm not sure if my solution is correct.

Here's what I did:
I first found the derivatives of $f(x)=1/x$:
$$f(x)=1/x$$
$$f'(x)=-1/x^2$$
$$f''(x)=2/x^3$$
$$f'''(x)=-6/x^4$$
$$f^{(4)}(x)=24/x^5$$
$$\vdots$$
$$f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^{n+1}n!/x^{n+1}$$

Then I used the formula for the Taylor series of $f(x)$ around $x=1$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(1)}{n!}(x-1)^n$$

Substituting the derivatives into the formula, I get:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!}(x-1)^n$$

For the convergence interval, I used the ratio test:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{(-1)^{n+2}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{(-1)^{n+1}}\frac{(x-1)^{n+1}}{(x-1)^n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x-1|}{n+1}=0$$

Therefore, the series converges for all $x$.

Now I'm not sure if my solution is correct or if there's any mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The $n!$ should vanish in the Taylor series.

Comment: Here is another answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1457086/121671)

Comment: @Oliver Díaz So, the Taylor Series around $x=a$ is 
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k!}f^{(k)}(a)(x-a)^k}$$

so an expression for the k-th derivative of $f(x)$ is needed:

$$f(x)=x^{-1} \implies f^{(k)}(x)=(-1)^k k! x^{-k-1}$$

so for $a=1$, $f^{(k)}(1)=(-1)^k k!$. Therefore, the Taylor-Maclaurin series is

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^k (x-1)^k}$$

with convergence for $-1 <x -1<1$.

Correct?

Comment: Correct! also if $f(x)=\sum_nc_n x^n$ for all $|x|<R$ the. $h(x):=f(x-a)=\sum_nc_n(x-a)^n$ for all $x$ such that $|x-a|<R$. This is a standard trick.